# How to unit test method with IAsyncEnumerable<dynamic> return type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, nunit, iasyncenumerable

I have a method:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<dynamic> Query(string name)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
      throw new ArgumentException("Name is missing", nameof(name));

   await foreach(var item in _myService.CallSomethingReturningAsyncStream(name))
   {
       yield return item;
   }
}
```

How to write an unit test for this method, using Nunit?

This is my current approach:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("")]
[TestCase(null)]
[TestCase("     ")]
public void TestQuery_GivenInvalidName_ShouldThrowException(string invalidName)
{     
    Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(
       async () => 
       await Task.FromResult(_queryService.Query(invalidName)
    );
}
```

I have tried using `Assert.Throws` and `Assert.ThrowsAsync`, but there is no result returned.

Comment: Did you try `async () => { await foreach (var x in _queryService.Query(invalidName)) { } }`

Comment: Or even simpler `async() => await _queryService.Query(invalidName).ToListAsync()`

Comment: The first one worked, but I don't see that extension method for the second (simpler) one. Please write both solutions as an answer so I can accept your answer

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? Do you want to verify that the async-enumerable sequence throws an `ArgumentException` on **the first** `MoveNextAsync` on the enumerator? Or that it throws on **some** `MoveNextAsync` during the eumeration, potentially the 1000th one? Or that it throws when the enumerator is instantiated, before even the first `MoveNextAsync`?

Comment: I gave implementation of Query method that I want to test, exception is thrown even before Iterator is initialized

Comment: Could you edit the question and specify this requirement? I could post an answer that tests this requirement, but most likely the test will fail. So you'll have to modify the `Query` method in order to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code actually enumerates the `IAsyncEnumerable` and checks if there is a `ArgumentException` occurring (at any stage of the enumeration):

```
Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(
   async () => { await foreach (var x in _queryService.Query(invalidName)) { } });
```

Using [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) this can be shortened to

```
Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(
   async () => await _queryService.Query(invalidName).ToListAsync());
```

Comment: The problem is that if this test fails, it might take a long to complete with failure. It might fetch millions of records from the database (or the Web) before the sequence completes successfully, and the assertion fails.

Comment: Yes. The OP did not specify when the exeption is expected, so I assume it can occur at any time. If it is guaranteed that it will occur on the 10th iteration latest, `Take(10)` can be added